# Setting Active Directory Properties

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm currnetly trying to set the four properties:

"Password never expires"
"Account is disabled"
"User must change password at next logon"
"User cannot change password"

I can set the first two using the lines in C#:

deUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val | 0x10000;
deUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val | 0x2;

though when I try to set the last two properties using the lines below they are not set.

deUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val | 0x800000;
deUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val | 0x0040;

Am I setting these last two properties to the right hex value? or should I be setting something different other then "userAccountControl"?

Thanks.

Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the `PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE` property by setting that flag; its value is readonly.  You must change it programmatically; this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746398%28VS.85%29.aspx) describes the procedure.